# CentOS 6.7 Error Configuring Non Routable Static IP in Home Office Environment

Tags: networking, centos-6

I have a virtual machine running CentOS 6.7 under VMware Workstation.  When it boots, or whenever I do a

```
sudo service network restart
```

I get the follwing error:

```
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

I'll describe the network configuration first, and then list a few additional symptoms.

First, the virtual machine is running under Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials in a home office environment.  The ISP is Time Warner Cable and the router's LAN facing IP is 192.168.0.1.  The MAC address specified in `ifcfg-eth0` (see below) was generated by VMware Workstation.  The IP addresses listed for the DNS servers (also below) are correct.

Contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:`

```
DEVICE=eth0
NAME=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO="static"
HWADDR=00:0C:29:50:95:68
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
IPADDR=192.168.0.9
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT="yes"
```

Contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network`

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=837025-web1.csnaps.org
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
NOZEROCONF=yes
```

After running sudo service network restart, the contents of /etc/resolv-conf

```
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search socal.rr.com csnaps.org
nameserver 209.18.47.62
nameserver 209.18.47.61
```

And the router table looks like:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

More symptoms:

I can ping other devices on my LAN (i.e. 192.168.0.xx) and other devices can ping the VM running CentOS.  I can start a Telnet/SSH session on 192.168.0.9 (the static IP I've assigned to the CentOS VM).

I cannot ping outside addresses (for example, 151.101.64.73, which is CNN.COM's IP address) but can from other machines.

I cannot resolve DNS names.  nslookup fails:

```
nslookup www.google.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

And I'm not sure this info is useful, but here's the output from `iptables -L -v -n:`

```
[csnaps@837025-web1 etc]$ sudo iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 11046 packets, 1405K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
 1013 76416 f2b-SSH    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 24402 packets, 1999K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain f2b-SSH (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
 1013 76416 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1:** In the Virtual Machine Settings for this machine, there is a single virtual network adapter configured as bridged, connect at power on and is, in fact, connected while the VM runs.  Replicate physical network connection state is not checked.

If I do a

`VM > Removable Devices > Network Adapter > Disconnect`

the VM responds with:

`eth0 NIC Link is Down`

If I then do a

`VM > Removable Devices > Network Adapter > Connect`

the VM responds with:

`eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None`

**UPDATE 2:**  Here's the Workstation's Virtual Network Editor settings:

[image]

Comment: The problem here will be on how VMware Workstation is configured, especially with respect to networking, which you haven't described at all. Please edit your question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Done.  Please let me know if there's anything else I should post.

Comment: What physical network adapter is it bridged to?

Comment: The machine has two adapters but only one is connected to the router.  There is nothing connected to the other NIC.  There are a number of other VMs running under Workstation (Ubuntu, Windows 10, etc) all with no issues.  The machine's LAN IP is 192.168.0.7.